# How can I edit `.reg` files with VIM?

Tags: vim, encoding, registry

by edit I mean the act of opening it, modifying it, and saving it.

I have some windows `.reg` files I want to edit from vim. It looks like I'm stuck at telling vim to use proper encoding when opening them:

[image]

commands like [`:e ++enc=latin-1`](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Reloading_a_file_using_a_different_encoding) are not working. 
What is the proper way to edit `.reg` files in windows gvim?

Comment: That looks like UTF-16 encoding? e.g. "unused UTF-16 byte" + "approximately ASCII byte".

Comment: @user2864740 but reloading the file in utf-16(in big endian or little endian) doesn't work, vim tells me it's not converted

Comment: It really *should* be readable as UTF-16-LE (forget about CPs) although it's missing the BOM ..

Answer (score 3):

It works for me. My settings are:

```
filetype on

:echo &filetype &encoding &fileencoding &ff
    registry utf-8 utf-16le dos
```

Answer (score 2):

You either need to explictly specify the encoding:

```
:edit ++enc=utf-16le file.reg
```

or ensure that `'fileencodings'` starts with `ucs-bom`, **and** you use a Unicode encoding (you'll probably need the latter also for the previous method to correctly see all characters):

```
:set encoding=utf-8
:set fencs^=ucs-bom
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe Windows uses a UTF-16 encoding, so try reloading the file with

```
:e! ++enc=utf-16le
```